# How does lichess rating compare with chess.com rating?

Tags: rating

I have accounts on both of these websites, but I don't know the difference of how they do the rating. Can anybody tell me at least a difference between lichess and chess.com rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say lichess is about +200

Comment: I agree its higher